# Update Customer metadata in stripe using dj-stripe in Django

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I'm integrating Stripe via dj-stripe into a Django project. Everything is working well, but I now want to add something in the [Customer metadata field](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create#create_customer-metadata) either at customer creation, or right after.

The problem is, I can't find how to add metadata to a customer object anywhere in the dj-stripe code ([here is the Customer model](https://github.com/dj-stripe/dj-stripe/blob/3a401ec01fc7fa9a1067f1923288b5c7abdd694d/djstripe/models/core.py#L398)), or docs.

It seems like fairly standard functionality, so I feel like I must be missing something.

Answer (score 1):

**There's an issue on GitHub regarding this.**

**As of 2017**

> We don't currently have any calls to add metadata to the customer object. You can currently add data locally via a custom Subscriber model

**This feature officially is not available. The alternative way according to maintainers is this:**

> At the moment, if you want to modify the upstream model (no matter the
> field), you have to use api_retrieve(). If we want to change that
> that's fine but a different issue.